# RabbitMQ consumer in the background

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, queue

Is it possible to run a RabbitMQ consumer (Pika) in a background (daemon) thread in Python?

For my use case, I would like one thread consumes messages and the main program does some scheduled work.

My attempt to was to set up and run a consumer in a daemon thread, but if my program exits, then I got warnings/errors in the RabbitMQ queue logs noting that a connection suddenly closed. I'm aware that I don't close the connection of my consumer running in the daemon thread.

The [example code](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.13.1/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) frequently quoted does not really fit my use case. It creates a thread for every message that the consumer receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to run a RabbitMQ consumer (Pika) in a background (daemon) thread in Python?

Yes

> My attempt to was to set up and run a consumer in a daemon thread, but if my program exits, then I got warnings/errors in the RabbitMQ queue logs noting that a connection suddenly closed. I'm aware that I don't close the connection of my consumer running in the daemon thread.

That's exactly what is expected to happen. It's not the end of the world to not correctly close a connection. If your consumer has outstanding messages that haven't been acked they will be re-queued.

Is there a specific reason you're using daemon threads as opposed to normal ones? https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects

> The example code frequently quoted does not really fit my use case. It creates a thread for every message that the consumer receives.

If you'd like assistance by far the most productive way is to provide a git repository that someone can clone, run and then provide feedback with.